# Refresh Kendo grid on PartialViewResult update

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, refresh, kendo-asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have an Ajax form in my view.
And a Kendo grid which is rendered in a partialview within the view.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddToCatalogue", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "catalogueSummary", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, new { id = "addToCatalogueForm" }))
{
    <input type="submit" class="button radius hide" id="btnAdd" value="Add to Catalogue" />
}

@Html.Partial("~/Views/Home/_CatalogueSummary.cshtml", Model.CatalogueItem)
```

In the partial I have the grid:

@using Web.Models
@model IEnumerable

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="panel">
        <h5>Summary</h5>
        <div id="divGrid">
            @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
                .Name("catalogueSummaryGrid")
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Bound(c => c.Name);
                    columns.Bound(c => c.Length);
                    columns.Bound(c => c.Description);
                    columns.Bound(c => c.Ref);
                })
                .Sortable()
                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .Group(groups => groups.Add(p => p.Type))
                .ServerOperation(false))
            )
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

SO I am firing the update from outside the partial in the main few, calling the action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult AddToCatalogue()
    {
        // Get the current state of this catalogue
        var api = new ServerApi<WebCatalogue>();
        var webCatalogue = api.GetRequest("WebCatalogue").Result;

        // Set up the UX state
        var catalogueItems = new List<CatalogueItem>();

        // Begin with existing items prior to this post
     catalogueItems.AddRange(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CatalogueItem>>(webCatalogue.Data));

        // Add in the dummy item
        var newItem = new CatalogueItem()
            {
            Type= "Single",
            Name = "Mark",
            Length = 5,
            Description = "some desc",
            Ref = "Ref 1"
            };
        catalogueItems.Add(CatalogueItem);

        // Apply the new UX state to the WebCatalogue and post it to the web api method
        var newItems = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(catalogueItems);
        webCatalogue.Data = newItems;
        api.PostRequest("WebCatalogue", webCatalogue);

        // Return the refreshed view
        return this.PartialView("_CatalogueSummary", catalogueItems);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Funny thing, sometimes by writing here a question I start analysing my code much deeper than I do searching for a bug (even though I analyse it very carefully before posting anything here), that only after posting the question I realise what the issue is.

In this case I was missing the div with id = "catalogueSummary" which had to be updated on ajax form posting.

Adding that solved the issue ha!